# Change directory in REXX exec running in z/OS USS?

Tags: zos, chdir, rexx, uss

I'm in the USS shell under TSO, and I have this exec (named *tryit*):

```
/* rexx */
"cd /differentdir"
"pwd"
```

Here's the result:

```
> pwd
/origdir
> tryit
/origdir
```

In other words, the effects of the *cd* command appear to last only for the duration of the command itself. Is there a way for the REXX exec to change the working directory in a way that will be recognized in following commands?

Comment: Look at the REXX syscalls environment. What you are doing is temporary, as by default each one of these commands is essentially a separate ADDRESS statement with the command string argument.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr That was exactly the prompting I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For REXX execs running under the USS shell, the default addressing environment is SH. From the *[Using REXX and z/OS UNIX System Services](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxb600/toc.htm)* manual:

> Note that built-in shell commands run in the shell process, not your REXX process and cannot alter the REXX environment. For example, address sh 'cd /' will not change the current directory of your REXX process.

To make a persistent change to the current working directory, issue the `address syscall chdir` command. From the same manual:

> If you use chdir to change a directory in a REXX program that is running in a
>   TSO/E session, the directory is typically reset to your home directory when the
>   REXX program ends.